Widgets with Webview are overflowing
When I create a structure with webview and SingleChildScrollView on a simple page, when I scroll the html gets mixed up with other widgets.
Expected results
Webview widget scrolls within itself without interfering with other widgets
Actual results
Webview widget scrolling by mixing with other widgets
 SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: Get.width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: HTMLWebView(
            htmlData: content,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
    ],
  ),
)

https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/fd885666-fa34-4bf4-a666-08e442213cb7

Add clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge in your SingleChildScrollView parent Container.
Example based on your code:
Container(
  height: 500, // your widget height
  width: double.infinity, // take all width
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        FlutterLogo(),
        FlutterLogo(),
        FlutterLogo(),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: Get.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: HTMLWebView(
              htmlData: content,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        FlutterLogo(),
        FlutterLogo(),
        FlutterLogo(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

*Why i add decoration when there's no need decorating container?
It is because to use clipBehavior we required to add decoration, otherwise error will be catched.
In the official doc:

The clip behavior when Container.decoration is not null.

References: clipBehavior Property

This did not work.

ow maybe i missunderstood about the code. Clip.hardEdge should hide the overflow element. Try to add the Clip.hardEdge to SingleChildScrollView parent. Let me edit my code

i edited my code, please adjust the container size to your needs

Actually, I already tried that. But it didn't work.

sorry for that, what package that u use? let me try it in my device

webview_flutter, I added the codes here, can you try it?
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/154823

ahh thanks i will try it

hello, i already attached my result in your github issues
